# fixing an image so that it does not move depending on the screen resolution?

Tags: html, image, screen, resolution, tumblr

I have an image of a person fixed in the background of my tumblr layout (my tumblr is tsuzami.tumblr.com), and it appears like so on my screen resolution of 1366 x 768:

http://oi39.tinypic.com/5x0f1g.jpg

but when previewed on screenfly using different screen resolutions, the person is placed in awkward location that obviously look stupid:

http://oi44.tinypic.com/f2yab.jpg

How would I lock this photo in the same place where I intended for it to be no matter the resolution? This is the code I am using for the image:

```
<div style="position:fixed; top: 0px; left:-140px; z-index:-2;"><img src="http://i43.tinypic.com/j7ca2u.png"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to avoid that, as the content area is 500px wide, and as the screen gets narrower (even on a desktop) the content will start to cover over the image. I would be more inclined to wrap the whole page in a container div and place the image as a background on that, and then set a min-width on the container. An easier way would be to remove that image div you have currently and just add these styles to the `body` element:

```
body {
background: url(http://i43.tinypic.com/j7ca2u.png) no-repeat -250px 0;
min-width: 1200px;
}
```

However, I'm not too keen about setting a min-width on the `body` element, so preferably add those styles above to a div that wraps around your whole page.